My Twitter Cards validate and Twitter Bot definitely retrieves my Twitter card meta tags but card image refuses to show
I am having a really hard time getting my Twitter card to show an image.  I have a route on my server that when given an image ID, serves up the proper meta tags to Twitterbot as the Twitter card definition.  I have put values for that route through the Twitter Card validator and it says the card loaded properly every time.  To isolate the cause, I took the URL to that route and plugged it directly into the Twitter web page, when composing a tweet, to make sure something else wasn't wrong when I used the Twitter share intent.  The image is 1024x1024 and it is 1.5MB, under the 5MB limit stated by the Twitter card docs page.
When I plug the Twitter card route directly into the Twitter client, I see Twitterbot access my route, but the card that appears does not have an image, just some default icon I guess it uses when it can't actually grab an image.
I have tried both the "summary" and "summary_large_image" card types, nothing works.  I tried a variety of different meta tag combinations as suggested by over 8 SO posts I read, still nothing works.  It's not a problem with robots.txt because my site does not have one.  It's not a problem with the fully qualified image URL because I can just paste it into my browser and the image shows.
Below is the console message from server reporting that Twitterbot (user-agent) accesses my route when I manually paste in the Twitter card route into a tweet being composed.  It also shows the actual HTML with meta tags being returned to Twitterbot.  Note, the domain names in the meta tag values have been replaced with example.com.  Also, if there appears to be an excess of tags because it is a result of not having any combination of tags work for me.  Here is the meta tag content
HTML returned to user agent:

Twitterbot/1.0

index.ts:231
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" name="Content-Type" />
            <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
            <meta name="twitter:title" content="Colorful Pogo Stick in Vibrant Park">
            <meta name="twitter:site" content="@human_for_now">
            <meta name="twitter:description" content="Experience the thrill of bouncing on a colorful pogo stick in a lively park filled with greenery and flowers, under the dappled sunlight.">
            <meta name="twitter:image" content="https://example.com/4c9f0456.png">
            <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://example.com/4c9f0456.png">
            <meta name="twitter:image:width" content="1024">
            <meta name="twitter:image:height" content="1024">
            <meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Experience the thrill of bouncing on a colorful pogo stick in a lively park filled with greenery and flowers, under the dappled sunlight.">
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>This page contains metadata for Twitter to display a rich preview of the image with ID: 4c9f0456.</p>

Is there other difficult to find or arcane piece of knowledge I am missing that can get this to work?
